# JqueryUi slider doesn't work in iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css">
<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And i have page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame" src="iframe.html" width="800" ></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frame').contents().find('#slider').slider({
        value:2,
        min: 0,
        max: 6,
        step: 1,
        animate: true,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want custom slider in iframe but this isn't work and i dont know why. This work perfect without iframe.

Update: Fix the problem by calling function that create slider from iframe

Comment: Update. I have Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js:351
(anonymous function)

Comment: Something tells me you can't instantiate a slider from the parent page, but that you would have to do that in the iframe.

Comment: but what's the reason for that?

Comment: u need to call this from frame, its for security reasons

Comment: No, but i try to declare  it now and it didnt help

Comment: The iframe is a page of it's own, you can access it from the parent page, or acces the parent from the child etc. but you can't expect things like the UI slider to be instatiated in an iframe by running the code in the parent window, it does'nt work like that.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is a separate html page ( a different document), without access to the parent's scripts,etc due to security reasons.

You need to include jQuery & jQuery UI in the iframe html document, and run the function within that document as well.

Here's a comprehensive write up of the why:
http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy